# C# MathNet FFT Definition

Tags: c#, fft, scaling, probability-density, mathnet-numerics

I have some problem when testing FFT from MathNet:
The idea is that if I apply FFT to the characteristic function of a gaussian variable I should find the gaussian density function.

When I plot VectorFFT the figure does seems a density function but in zero it does not have value 1, it has value 1.4689690914109.

There must be some problems with the scaling. I tried out all type of FourierOptions in Fourier.Inverse and all type of divisions/multiplications for PI, 2PI, sqrt(2PI) but nothing gives me the value 1 at the center of the density function.

Also, since various definitions of Fourier Transform and its inverse exists, I was wondering which one is implemented by MathNet, I could not find it in the documentation.

Any ideas?

```
public void DensityGaussian()
    {
        double eta = 0.1;   //step in discrete integral
        int pow2 = 256;     // N^2
        double mu = 0;      // centred gaussian
        double sigma = 1;   // with unitary variance

        //FFT
        double lambda = 2 * System.Math.PI / (pow2 * eta);
        double b = 0.5 * pow2 * lambda;

        Complex[] VectorToFFT = new Complex[pow2];
        for (int j = 0; j < pow2; j++)
        {
            double z = eta * j;

            if (z == 0) { z = 0.00000000000001; }

            VectorToFFT[j] = System.Numerics.Complex.Exp(new Complex(0, b * z));
            VectorToFFT[j] *= (System.Numerics.Complex.Exp(new Complex(
                              -sigma*sigma*z*z, mu * z))); //char function of gaussian
        }

        Fourier.Inverse(VectorToFFT, FourierOptions.NoScaling);

        //scaling
        for (int i = 0; i < pow2; i++)
        {
            VectorToFFT[i] /= (2 * System.Math.PI); //test
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Is density?");
        Assert.IsTrue(1 == 1);
    }
```

Comment: The FFT implements the Discrete Fourier Transform. The DFT is not the same as the (continuous) Fourier Transform.

Answer (score 0):

Math.NET Numerics supports all common [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) definitions, controllable with the `FourierOptions` flags enum. They essentially vary on the exponent and on the scaling.

The [FourierOptions docs](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.IntegralTransforms/FourierOptions.htm) give some hints on how the options affect the effective definition, essentially:

- InverseExponent: use a negative sign in the exponent (default uses a positive sign). A prominent implementation with a negative sign is numerical recipes.
- AsymmetricScaling/NoScaling: instead of the default symmetric scaling `sqrt(1/N)` either only scale in the inverse transformation `1/N` (like Matlab) or no scaling at all (like numerical recipes). Obviously, without scaling `ifft(fft(x)) != x`.

Maybe the answer in [Calculating a density from the characteristic function using fft in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029956/calculating-a-density-from-the-characteristic-function-using-fft-in-r) can help on the specific use case.